# Failed to fetch, after clean installation of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, updates

Located in Sweden, Europe, getting below errors when performing update/upgrade. 
Anyone knows how to solve this. If cannot be solve what are the consquences?

Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.6_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 54.192.98.176 80]

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem - the link works properly for me. Are you, perhaps, behind some organizational firewall that requires proxies?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue this morning. I changed the protocol in sources.list from HTTP to FTP and that solved it.

Comment: Just curious... Why could that have solved it?